# How to write ether/Ether (start with capital case)?

Tags: ether

I am writing a paper and I know this has something to do with the English but I have decided to ask here because when you think deeply enough you realize this question requires some knowledge about blockchain and the Ethereum: **How to write e(E)ther?** Should it start with a capital case or not? Is e(E)ther a common noun or a proper noun? I am confused because according to [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17517/why-arent-currency-names-capitalized):

```
Australian dollar, not Australian Dollar.
```

Since e(E)ther is a "token", we should say "Ether token" but no one says that. And when we think about it: Ethereum is an isolated world and the "token" in that world is referred as "ether". So, I guess this makes it a "common noun".

**Another question would be:** "Is e(E)ther a currency?" The answer to this question could also help with my main question.

Answer (score 0):

In the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) it is used by capital e, like Ether. I think this is the right one. Because yellow paper is a very technical paper.

And the second answer is, yes. Ether is a currency, and Ethereum is an ecosystem. People usually use these wrong.